# how to extract data from refernce of shared_ptr<T&>

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr

This is my function definition

```
void subscribe(std::shared_ptr<StrategyOrderEvents &> &strategy)
{
     auto p=make_pair(strategy.get()->m_StrategyName,strategy);
}
```

but when I'm trying to do `strategy.get()` I am getting the following error:

> ‘class std::shared_ptr’ has no member named
>   ‘get’

inside the `StrategyOrderEvents` class, I have a data member name and I wont to extract it

*Edit Notice
the get()->get() was a try i fix that to strategy.get()->m_StrategyName

Comment: Im using std::shred_ptr all over my code

Comment: This error doesn't make sense given the code you show. You should do `strategy.get()`, not `strategy->get()` to access the raw pointer. But you don't want the raw pointer anyway, so don't do any `.get()`, just `strategy->m_StrategyName`... And `->get()->get()` is also nonsensical. Please ensure that the error you show can be reproduced with the code you show so that we can give you a coherent answer.

Comment: @MaxLanghof i edit the code it was a try, and when im doing 'strategy->m_StrategyName' im getting "base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::shared_ptr<StrategyOrderEvents&>’"
     auto p = std::make_pair(strategy->m_StrategyName,strategy);'

Comment: Why would you even want to write such code? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to form shared (or other) pointers to references.

Either do

```
void subscribe(std::shared_ptr<StrategyOrderEvents>& strategy)
```

or do

```
void subscribe(StrategyOrderEvents& strategy)
```

(and preferably add `const` correctness).

You are currently accepting a reference to a shared pointer to a reference to an object. That's already way too many references from a code design standpoint (but the compiler only complains because forming a pointer to reference is illegal).

The error message is not helpful, but your C++ implementation presumably implements the `std::shared_ptr` template in a way that leaves it as an empty class when instantiated with a reference type, somewhat like

```
template<class T>
class shared_ptr {
    // real implementation
};

template<T>
class shared_ptr<T&> {}; // empty class for invalid usage
```

Comment: tnx i change it to 'void subscribe(std::shared_ptr<StrategyOrderEvents>& strategy)'